# Using split function inside ngIf condition in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<div *ngIf="store[obj?.FundCode + obj?.PayWith].status == 'fail'">test</div>
```

I am using the above syntax to concatenate two strings to map an array. It works fine but when I try to use split function like below I get template parse errors.

```
<div *ngIf="store[obj?.FundCode + obj?.PayWith.split(/[ ,]+/).join('-')].status == 'fail'">test</div>
```

when I use the split function inside `ngIf` like above, the app is throwing an error: template parse error. I am having trouble to find out how to escape the split function and properly execute it.

Comment: Probably not the answer you are looking for, but a better design would be to do this logic inside your component.ts file

Comment: Thanks @MCMatan. Yes I would go with that solution if I don't get any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer not using complicated syntax inside HTML, even is it true syntax; it will be confused.

You can use `getter` function as variable; simply like this:

```
get isFailed() : boolean {
    // Check if obj is defined to avoid errors.
    if(! this.obj) return false;

    let key = this.obj.FundCode + obj?.PayWith.split(/[ ,]+/).join('-');
    return this.store[key].status == 'fail';
}
```

Then use this variable in HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="isFailed"> test </div>
```

That's will be clearer and should solve your issue.

Read more about  [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)